# Inconsistency while search in ElasticSearch 2.0.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am doing 3 consecutive steps as **1- INDEXING, 2- SEARCHING, 3-DELETING**.
My mapping:

```
PUT _template/discoveryes
{
                "template" : "discoveryes-*",

                "settings" : {
                    "number_of_shards" : 3,
                    "number_of_replicas" : 0,
                    "index": {
                        "analysis": {
                            "filter": {

                                "en_stop_filter": {
                                  "type": "stop",
                                  "stopwords": ["_english_"]
                                } , "en_stem_filter": {
                                  "type": "stemmer",
                                  "name": "english"
                                }
                            },
                            "analyzer": {
                            "en_analyzer": {
                              "type": "custom",
                              "filter": ["icu_normalizer", "en_stop_filter", "en_stem_filter", "icu_folding"],
                              "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
                            },

                            "default": {
                              "type": "custom",
                              "filter": ["icu_normalizer", "icu_folding"],
                              "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                },   

                "mappings" : {
                    "discoveryes": {
                        "_source" : { 
                            "enabled" : "true" 
                        },

                            "properties" : {
                                "witID" : {
                                    "type" : "string",
                                    "index" :"not_analyzed"
                                },
                                "text" : {
                                    "type" : "string",
                                    "analyzer" : "en_analyzer"
                                },
                                "docID":{
                                    "type":"string",
                                    "index" :"not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                    }

                }
            }
```

During my 1st operation, I am getting the correct result(means I am indexing few docs and searching some keywords which is giving me correct result and then deleting all the indexed ids).

But I am not getting the same result when I am trying to do the same operation again for same documents.

When I am commenting the delete operation and doing the operations then I am getting correct results everytime, but the problem arises when I include the DELETE operation.
I am doing all these operation using Java.

Code for Search Operation :

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = client
                                .prepareSearch()
                                .setIndices("discoveryes-1")
                                .setTypes("discoveryes").setQuery(qb)
                                .setSize(100);
```

Code for DELETE Operation :

```
DeleteResponse rsp = client.prepareDelete().setIndex("discoveryes-1").setType("discoveryes")
                    .setId(witID)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
```

In the above line of code, the witID is the indexed ID based on which I am deleting.

Could I get some help regarding this?
Thanks

Comment: Please specify how are you using java Api? I mean show us the code.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am getting inconsistent result. Like sometimes 3 search results (which is correct) and 1, 2, 0 also, which makes it inconsistent.

Comment: After using delete api your records will obviously vary as some of the documents are getting deleted

Comment: I have empty Index, I indexed some documents, searched and then deleted all the docs indexed. Now again empty index. And I am repeating the same operation, so technically whatever data is getting indexed, are being deleted too. So it shouldn't matter. Search result should be the same. And I am not just searching for text. I am specifying the IDs also.